# Angular 2 dynamically changing directive properties in HTML

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I'm using a component that contains a "widget" directive which currently includes some hard-coded variables in the component template. Something like this:

```
<widget image="{{imageUrl}}" [theme]="{color: blue, hue: '600'}"></widget>
```

Now I want to dynamically generate these directives and I'm not sure how to insert just the color from an array of colors. It would look something like this:

```
<div *ngFor='let user of _allusers; let rowIndex = index'>
   <widget image="{{imageUrl}}" [theme]="{color: colors[rowIndex], hue: '600'}"></widget>
</div>
```

Maybe I'm mistaken, but I don't think setting the entire "theme" string is the answer since the color changes as part of the template loop--not with some event/action in the component code. Can I do this in the component template, or do I need to change the directive?

Comment: How does `colors` array look like?

Comment: @yurzui I just created a string array for it: ["blue","red","orange","gray"] eventually I'll randomize it, but I'm just trying to get it working first

Comment: `[theme]="{ color: colors[rowIndex], hue: '600'}"`

Comment: @yurzui, sorry there was a typo in my question. what you just wrote was the first thing I tried. it doesn't work inside the string. I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" since color is undefined

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/t4j2VuFL9B1BqXKLEhD6?p=preview

Comment: Are you getting `colors` from server?

Comment: Try this `[theme]="{ color: colors && colors[rowIndex], hue: '600'}"`

Comment: @yurzui thanks!!! That was an effective way to tell me I was wrong. :)  It turns out that the directive was checking the color hues against the site theme and only certain colors are in the theme. So the code works fine as long as I stick to the right colors. Otherwise the color is "undefined." If you add your plnkr as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible you did something wrong in your code but this should work

**template.html**

```
<div *ngFor='let user of _allusers; let rowIndex = index'>
  <div>{{user.name}}</div>
  <widget [theme]="{ color: colors[rowIndex], hue: '600'}"></widget>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'black']
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/t4j2VuFL9B1BqXKLEhD6?p=preview)**